# Good Android user interface design - when to add an explicit cancel button?

Tags: android, user-interface

I was wondering, since on Android one closes a screen by pressing the "return" round-arrow, is it still OK to have a cancel button on each screen or does it look rather clumpsy and confuse because the user might think it does something different than the return button.

Is there a good rule or even guideline for this ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On each screen it's from my point of view useless, you are suppose to go to your previous screen (previous Activity since one screen is one Activity... usually) with the back button. For dismissing an AlertDialog, keyboard, ProgressDialog : back button is still ok. Where a cancel button can be added is when the user is processing a complex chain of action and in the middle of it he thinks : screw this... here a cancel button which bring him back to your home Activity is welcome.

Downloading lots of app and look at their application's flow (navigation between screens) will teach you what's intuitive, natural and what's not.

Personal thoughts.